# Insert JavaScript into a JavaScript alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ip-address

Here is the button that load the alert and the alert itself:

```
<center><button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button></center>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("blablabla");
}
```

And here is the code that I want the alert to load:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://en.dnstools.ch/out/4.js">
```

The visitor click on the button, it display an alert with it's external IP. I tried innerHTML but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you own `http://en.dnstools.ch` domain, and is controlled by you ? Because then and then only you will be able to do that

Comment: I don't think you can do it with raw JS, `alert` function only takes one string as argument.

Comment: Can you use PHP to solve this? There was a very good answer showing how to do it in PHP, but it was deleted. If you can't use PHP to solve it, please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: Your question is contradictory.  An `alert` is displaying a message on screen, it doesn't load any code.  If you are to load some code, you can do it alongside the alert.  However, since the code you are trying to load uses `document.write`, replacing original page, no code will work after this call using `<script>` as others suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file http://en.dnstools.ch/out/4.js contains the following JavaScript:

```
document.write('[your ip]');
```

where `[your ip]` is the actual visitors IP. Since it uses `document.write` you can not put it directly in an alert. What the method does is writing directly to the HTML document (if it is open, if not it clears it). It is an old method and it is not a good idea to use it. But since I assume you do not control this code, you might not have an option if you want to use this particular service.

So how do you get it into an alert? Try putting this HTML anywhere in your body:

```
<div id="ip" style="display:none;">
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://en.dnstools.ch/out/4.js"></script>
</div>
```

This will give you a hidden div with the IP inside. Now you can alert it (as soon as the DOM is ready) in JavaScript like this:

```
alert(document.getElementById("ip").textContent);
```

Since the client can easily modify the IP you get by this method, do not use this for any security purposes.

Comment: Doesn't work, the alert display this : <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://en.dnstools.ch/out/4.js">
</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Fixed it. It has to do with how you close the `script` tag, and using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the id `ip` to the div containing this ip you will be able to grab it if it is included before your `myFunction`. Then `$("#myIdContainingTheIp").html()` will contain your ip and you will be able to alert it.

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery you can do it in the following way:

```
<center><button id="clickMe">Click me</button></center>
    <span style="display:none;"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://en.dnstools.ch/out/4.js"></script></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    alert($('span').text());
}

$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    myFunction();
});
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/hqa7nahx/1/)

Comment: Just use `$('#clickMe').click(myFunction);` instead of declaring an inline function that calls `myFunction`. Nice solution!